# Unknown column 'Rating' in 'having clause'

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT
  r.Restaurant_ID,
  r.Name
FROM Restaurant r
JOIN Review rv on r.Restaurant_ID = rv.Restaurant_ID
HAVING AVG(Rating) > Rating
ORDER BY Restaurant_ID;
```

Copy response:

> Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'Rating' in 'having clause'

I will leave my full code below:

```
CREATE TABLE Restaurant (
  Restaurant_ID INT NOT NULL,
  Name varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  Cuisine_Type varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  Address varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  City varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  Phone_Number varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  Dine_Type varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (Restaurant_ID)
);

INSERT INTO Restaurant VALUES ('1', 'MC Donald´s', 'Fastfood', 'Street', 'Cork', '111-1111', 'Yes');

SELECT * FROM Restaurant;

CREATE TABLE Customer (
  Customer_ID INT NOT NULL,
  Name varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  Address varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  Age decimal NOT NULL,
  Gender varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (Customer_ID)
);

INSERT INTO Customer VALUES ('1', 'Ryu', 'Street', '30', 'Male');

SELECT * FROM Customer;

CREATE TABLE Review (
  Review_ID INT NOT NULL,
  Restaurant_ID INT NOT NULL,
  Customer_ID INT NOT NULL,
  Rating varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  Date varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (Review_ID),
  FOREIGN KEY (Restaurant_ID) REFERENCES Restaurant (Restaurant_ID),
  FOREIGN KEY (Customer_ID) REFERENCES Customer (Customer_ID)
);

INSERT INTO Review VALUES ('1', '1', '1', '5', '01/01/2016');

SELECT * FROM Review;

SELECT COUNT(Restaurant_ID) , Dine_Type FROM Restaurant WHERE LOWER(City) = 'cork';

SELECT r.Restaurant_ID, r.Name FROM Restaurant r JOIN Review rv on r.Restaurant_ID = rv.Restaurant_ID HAVING AVG(Rating) > Rating ORDER BY Restaurant_ID;

SELECT c.Name , COUNT(Review_ID) From Customer c JOIN Review rv ON c.customer_ID = rv.customer_ID ORDER BY c.Name;

SELECT r.Name,r.Address,r.Cuisine_Type,rv.Date,rv.Rating,c.Name FROM Restaurant r JOIN Review rv ON r.Restaurant_ID = rv.Restaurant_ID JOIN Customer ON rv.customer_ID = c.customer_ID ORDER BY c.Name;

SELECT r.Name FROM Restaurant r JOIN Review rv ON r.Restaurant_ID=rv.Restaurant_ID WHERE rv.Rating >= 8 AND rv.Date LIKE %2016% AND rv.Date LIKE %2017% GROUP BY r.City HAVING COUNT(Review_ID) > 20 ORDER BY r.Name LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: Please consider following [these suggestions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql/2977#2977).

Answer (score 2):

It seems you want to select all rows which have `Rating` higher than the average `Rating`.

**You cannot do this with standard aggregation** because once you have aggregated, the original rows simply do not exist anymore, only the aggregation.

In your case, you have `HAVING` with no `GROUP BY`, that implies `GROUP BY ()` (grouping by the empty set), and then you only have a single row. So the `Rating` column is simply not available without using an aggregation function.

**You could use window functions in MySQL 8.0+:**

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT
      r.Restaurant_ID,
      r.Name,
      Rating,
      AVG(Rating) OVER () AvgRating
    FROM Restaurant r
    JOIN Review rv on r.Restaurant_ID = rv.Restaurant_ID
) r
WHERE AvgRating > Rating
ORDER BY Restaurant_ID;
```

Alternatively, *in SQL Server*, you could also use `TOP (50) PERCENT`, although this gives you the median, not the mean.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT TOP (50) PERCENT
      r.Restaurant_ID,
      r.Name,
      Rating
    FROM Restaurant r
    JOIN Review rv on r.Restaurant_ID = rv.Restaurant_ID
    ORDER BY Rating DESC
) r
ORDER BY Restaurant_ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have 3 ratings:

- From one user for one restaurant
- An average for a restaurant
- An overall average for all restaurants.

Give this a try:

```
SELECT  Restaurant_ID, Name
    FROM  
        ( SELECT  r.Restaurant_ID,
                  r.Name, 
                  ( SELECT  AVG(Rating)
                    FROM  Review
                    WHERE  Restaurant_ID = r.Restaurant_ID 
                  ) AS rate1
            FROM  Restaurant AS r 
        ) AS x
    JOIN  
        ( SELECT  AVG(Rating) AS avg_rate
            FROM  Review 
        ) AS overall
    WHERE  x,rate1 > overall.avg_rate
    ORDER BY  Restaurant_ID;
```

As for the title question, note that I went to a subquery to avoid such an error.

Answer (score -2):

The querie first calculate the total rating of each restaurant and then return restaurant who have rating < AVGRating

```
SET sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));
```

```
select r.Restaurant_ID, r.Name, max(r.rate) as rate 
  from (select r.Restaurant_ID, r.Name, Rating, AVG(Rating)  OVER (PARTITION BY r.Restaurant_ID ORDER BY r.Restaurant_ID ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) rate,
AVG(Rating) OVER () AvgRating FROM Restaurant r  
JOIN Review rv on r.Restaurant_ID = rv.Restaurant_ID ) r 
WHERE AvgRating > r.rate 
ORDER BY Restaurant_ID;



+---------------+--------------+------+
| Restaurant_ID | Name         | rate |
+---------------+--------------+------+
|             1 | MC Donald´s  |  5.5 |
+---------------+--------------+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Please do not post multiple answers like you've been doing on this question.  Once you get enough [reputation](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you'll be able to [comment on any post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment), until then please provide actionable answers to questions you *can* answer without [requiring clarification](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).